# REST design - An operation with multiple possible non-success payloads

Tags: rest

I'm trying to design a REST method for an 'Add person' operation that has a bunch of business rules. There are multiple possible non-success payloads (for the business purposes), requiring defined structure (to allow the consumer to parse the detail).

For 'Add a person', one of the following non-successes could happen:

1. We believe the system already has person.

   - Payload: The ID of that person
2. There are some possible matches.

   - Payload: A list of possible duplicates, and an override code to submit the record 'for sure'
3. General validation errors

   - Payload: Array of 'Error' object. (Standard across the API)

**Question - Response object**

If they're all to return under a single HTTP error status code, would it be right to have a varied object like:

- OverrideCode (for (1))
- PersonPossibleMatches [] (also for (1))
- PersonDuplicateId (for (2))
- ErrorList [] (for (3))

And have the consumer + documentation explain the interpretation?

**Question - Response code**

Is 400 (Bad Request) the correct (or correct enough) HTTP status code for this? We use it largely for the field validation (also scenario (3) - just wondering if business rule / 'intermediate state' things like this are any different.

Are there a more appropriate codes to spread the 3x scenarios over? And is it ok for the payloads to be different?

Thanks.

Comment: Be *very* careful with your approach to item #2. This has the potential to be a giant security hole. I'm sort of grimacing thinking about what information you would be returning and who has access to that API end point.

Comment: The 'possible matches' in #2 have the same visibility as the person search endpoint in our system. Cheers for the heads up though.

Comment: Good to know :-). Stay cautious, my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends in part on how the operation is performed. Since you said the operation has a bunch of business rules, and the system returns a payload with an ID when the person already exists, let's assume the operation is non-idempotent due to unrelated side-effects, performed with a POST to a factory endpoint.

**1. We believe the system already has person.**

This is a no-brainer. As suggested by others, you should use a `409 Conflict` status code, with a body describing the nature of the conflict. In this case, it seems like there's nothing else the user needs to do, and he can move forward to the next step in the workflow. If there's something he can do, it should follow a procedure similar to the next case.

**2. There are some possible matches.**

Assuming that the clients don't have any key to unambiguously identify a person, which seems to be your case since you're considering possible matches, here you should also use a `409 Conflict` status code, with a body describing the nature of the conflict, but with instructions on how to solve it.

Some other answer suggests you to allow an overwrite parameter that could be used any time, other suggests using a `PUT`, but I disagree with that since there's nothing preventing a client from using the overwrite all the time, or skipping the `POST` and use the `PUT` to replace an existent close-match. Also, you may have concurrent clients trying to add or change a person that match each other, or a common existent group, which will lead to an ABA conflict.

The conflict resolution body should return a valid tag for each possible match, and the client should be instructed to resubmit the same request with the `If-Match` header and the collection of tags. It may be a single tag, as long as it's generated from key data from each member in the collection. This will enforce that the user first must try the request without any override. If there's a conflict the user is forced to specify the exact entities that will be overwritten, and you're protected from inconsistent updates in case someone changes the current state between the first and the second request.

If the tags don't match in the second request, meaning the state was changed by something else between them, you should fail with a `412 Precondition Failed` error.

**3. General validation errors**

This is also a no-brainer. A `400 Bad Request` detailing the error, which seems to be standard across your API.

Comment: the thing preventing PUT all the time is that the client wouldnt know what URL to PUT to until they got the POST response telling them of the possible conflict

Comment: That makes sense if in a close match the client will create a new one, but if the client replaces an existent one, there's nothing preventing him from doing the replacement without the POST. That's the case I had in mind.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with clients using overwrite semantics all the time, if that's what the OP's application design permits.

Comment: The fact that something is allowed won't prevent the problems caused by it. Allowing unconditional overwrites will allow clients to overwrite other's data during conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

There are two aspects you need to consider

1. HTTP response code.
2. Error response payload.

Point number 1 is relatively simple. You have 400 error code for bad requests. And 409 for conflicting resources. So far simple.

Now let us consider your scenarios:

> 1. We believe the system already has person.
>      Payload: The ID of that person

Design suggestion: you can send a response like below

```
Response code: 409

{
    "error_code": "resource_exists",
    "error_description": "Resource person with ID XXX already exists"
    "debug_info": "",
    "link" : [
        {
            "href": "http://host-name/persons/123456",
            "rel": "person"
        }
    ]
}




2. There are some possible matches.
    Payload: A list of possible duplicates, and an override code to submit the record 'for sure'
```

Design suggestion:
In this case - you may want to use PUT to override the resource. No need to use special code.

```
Response Code: 400
{
    "error_code": "potential_duplicates",
    "error_description": "Potentially the resource is duplicate of one of the following. Please use PUT with the resource ID to update"
    "debug_info": "",
    "link" : [
        {
            "href": "http://host-name/persons/234",
            "rel": "person"
        },
                {
            "href": "http://host-name/persons/456",
            "rel": "person"
        },
        {
            "href": "http://host-name/persons/789",
            "rel": "person"
        }
    ]
}
```

> 1. General validation errors
>      Payload: Array of 'Error' object. (Standard across the API)

Design suggestion: Here you can simply use 400 response code and a meaningful response like the examples above.

Answer (score 2):

You could use 409 for the duplicate entry - and arguably for the possible duplicate entries with the extra info in the payload.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10

A 400 for validation errors would be the expected response.

It is a judgement call at the end of the day and it depends what would be easier for your rest clients and what they are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the design process I use when creating RESTful API responses for error cases:

1. Design the response payload for the error condition. Regardless of the error code that's used, it is always good practice to return some content within error responses so that clients can learn more about the error and how to avoid it in the future.
2. If there is an HTTP status code that accurately describes this error already, and it's not already in use for another error case, use that.
3. If the closest matching error code is already being used for another error case, it's still OK to  use that code, but the response payload becomes the place where the different error cases under that code get distinguished from each other. Your documentation should clearly state that inspecting this code wouldn't be enough, and that clients should then also look into the response to see exactly what happened.
4. If none of the above are applicable, use the closest error code that's appropriate. Just as in #3, the documentation of your response payloads makes this approach possible. If it's an error that the client influenced, make it a 400-range error, probably `400 - Bad Request`. If it's the server's fault, then it should be a 500-range error, probably `500 - Internal Server Error`.
5. Please, *please*, never throw `200 - OK` for errors. The world left that nonsense behind in SOAP land, and nobody wants to go back.

Now let's apply that thinking to your error cases:

- `We believe the system already has that person.` As correctly stated in another answer, `409 - Conflict` accurately describes that error, so you should just use that. Putting some descriptive error information in the response payload would help new users of your API, even with such a definitive and understandable code.
- `There are some possible matches.` There really isn't an HTTP code that describes this, and it's something that the client could influence, so the closest would be the catch-all code of `400 - Bad Request`. Including the list of possible duplicates is an interesting idea, but make sure you don't end up returning enormous responses with huge numbers of possible matches. Also, make sure to also return URIs to those matching resources so that your clients can easily consume them. As for the "override code" suggestion, I wouldn't return that in the payload. Rather, I'd just document a parameter to your "Add a Person" operation that would allow for overrides to occur at any time, not just after a failed first attempt. For example: `POST /people?overwrite=true`.
- `General validation errors` This is definitely a job for `400 - Bad Request`, along with a descriptive error payload. It sounds like you're already allowing an array of errors to be returned from any API call, so that should be good enough to capture all the validation failures for the client-supplied data.

Comment: Aren't you effectively using a querystring parameter to modify data with that approach, or the idea behind is that you have two people factories, one that allows overwrites and the other don't? I'm a little uncomfortable with a querystring parameter changing the behavior when creating or updating data.

Comment: If the request is a POST or PUT, then it's perfectly reasonable for it to create or update data. Parameters that come after `?` are usable in all kinds of requests, not just read-only `GET`s.

Comment: Well... thinking of URI querystring as request parameters is too RPCish for my taste. An URI is an atomic identifier and the semantics should be irrelevant for the application. Since the RFC 3986, when you add a parameter to the URI you're not adding a parameter to your call in the same way you do when you add a parameter to the body, you're effectively changing the identified resource, hence my question, if the idea behind that is having two people factories. If you're thinking in terms of parameters, your intent is clear, but that's RPC, not REST.

Comment: The point of contention here which is whether query parameters are part of the resource identifier. This is one area that I side more with practicalities than with specs: most web server frameworks (PHP, etc) will allow parameters to flow to an app in either URI strings as query parameters, or as data within request content. So for me, the resource identification ends at the `?`. I see your point though, and it has a simple solution which is to pass the same "behavior modification" instructions within the request body. I don't agree that using that pattern makes an API become RPC, though.

Comment: I don't know most web server frameworks, but I doubt they don't distinguish between URI query parameters and data. I don't see how that's siding with practicality. Anyway, if that works for you, go ahead..

Answer (score 0):

How about explaining it with a payload back; That is how we deal with REST responses for clients.

Response HTTP 409 with following payload response indicating to client what should they do next
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<request-result>
<http-code>200</http-code>
<description>REST Request is successfully processed</description>
<internal-error-info>Person already Exists</internal-error-info>
<message>Person with <id> already exists in sytem. Try picking different ID/Name combination</message>
<requested-operation>Add a Person</requested-operation>
<resource-name>Person</resource-name>
<status>SUCCESSFUL</status>
</request-result>
```

`